# Outliers appearing in box plot when I use plotly with ggplot2 (R)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have a problem with outliers appearing when they shouldn't when I use plotly, and I'm wondering how to stop this from happening.  I'll use the mtcars dataset as an example.

I'll set an obvious outlier:

```
 mtcars[1,1] = 60
```

The first plot, with outliers included:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
+   geom_boxplot(
+       aes(x = cyl, y = mpg, group = cyl))
```

[image]

Now I make a plot with outliers removed:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_boxplot(
      aes(x = cyl, y = mpg, group = cyl), 
      outlier.shape = NA)
```

[image]

Now I convert the plot to ggplotly and save

```
p <- plotly::ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

The outliers are showing.  Does anyone know how I can get around this problem / have a solution when using ggplotly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
    p$x$data[[i]]$marker <- list(opacity = 0)
}
```